# PHP separate parts of string

Tags: php, html, css

```
$ekipa = "Admini-aruturek,Kura126"                      
$rangi = explode('-', $ekipa);
foreach ($rangi as $ranga){     #I know that is no correct.                 
    echo($ranga[1]);   #This is not correct!
    echo($ranga[2]);   #This is not correct!
}
```

Ok, I want to separate the first part of string and second part. e.g.
Admini-aruturek,Kura126
to 
Admini
and
aruturek,Kura126

And from "Admini-aruturek,Kura126" to:
echo "Admini";
echo "aruturek,Kura126"

How to do that?

Comment: How does this relate to Centre DIV text? You explode with "-" and then you can also insert linebreaks so add <BR> to the end of strings, 
print $range[1]."<br>";

Comment: Read the `foreach` manual and array indexes starts with 0.

Comment: use $ranga[0], $ranga[1]

Comment: Table numeration starts from 0 not from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this what you mean? You say team name is Admini, but then you say you want to display aruturek along with Kura126?

```
$ekipa = "Admini-aruturek,Kura126";                      
$rangi = explode(',', $ekipa);
foreach ($rangi as $ranga) {                 
    if (strstr($ranga, '-') !== false) {
        list($name, $name2) = explode('-', $range);
    } else {
        $name = $ranga;
    }
    echo $name . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value like

```
<?php
$ekipa = "Admini-aruturek,Kura126"           ;           
$rangi = explode('-', $ekipa);

foreach ($rangi as $ranga){                         
   echo $ranga.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get 0 and 1 index of `$rangi` array Try

```
$ekipa = "Admini-aruturek,Kura126";                   
$rangi = explode('-', $ekipa);
echo $rangi[0];//Admini
echo $rangi[1]; //aruturek,Kura126
```

for both

```
echo $rangi[0].$rangi[1];
```